# possibility of changing the corresponding author in IEEE transaction

Tags: authorship, ieee, correspondence

Is it possible to assign one of the other authors as corresponding author in IEEE transactions during the peer review (i.e. changing the corr author) by any reason? If yes, at which stages it is possible? Is it possible when a paper received the A.Q (Accepted with mandatory minor revisions) status?

If not, is it possible to add the second corresponding author at any stage of peer review?

Comment: Any change you would want to make should be immediately mailed to the editors or wherever the journal tells you to do so. Just state the reason clearly and ask for the change. Generally they tend to accept most changes prior to publishing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but explain why you're making the change to the editor(s). Changing the authors of a paper is suspicious, but if you have a good reason to do it (e.g. original corresponding author moved/died/graduated, new corresponding author took over the project, etc) then the journal/publisher usually won't object.

Odds are you can make changes all the way up till you get the proofs, if you have good reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you also please give me some information about the possibility of **adding** a second corresponding author to the paper? Is it possible to have two corresponding author simultaneously in IEEE?

Comment: I doubt adding multiple corresponding authors is possible.  Otherwise, more authors would simply claim papers without doing the actual work.